# Mocha run after all tests in all classes run

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

So I am using mocha and I have over 10 JS classes of tests. I have built a log variable that lives for throughout the test runs over these 10 classes. Now what I want to do is after the last test runs, I want to write this log to a file.

So the first thing I did was write something like this in every class

```
test.afterEach(function() {
    currentTest = this.currentTest;

    if(currentTest.state === 'failed') {
        common.takeScreenshot(driver, common.getTestName() + " - Failed.jpg");
    }

    common.writerLoggerToFile(this.currentTest.title+ ".json");

    driver.quit();
});
```

This will create a file for each test. I know I could do test.after that would reduce it to one file per class. The thing I noticed in the last file that gets created has all the data from all the tests. So I would like it to be one file.

Note: These files are storing data in json so I cannot simply append the file so easily. Any thoughts if mocha has a solution or do I need to build one? Thanks

Comment: Can you add an example of what is being logged to the question?

Comment: Here are some relevant official docs: https://mochajs.org/#root-hook-plugins - it is possible to accomplish using a root hook when running tests in serial

Answer (score 3):

You can also wrap your tests into one suite, in the root suite you can initialize necessary stuff like DB connection, etc. Then, you can pass necessary information between suites using the [global variable](https://stackabuse.com/using-global-variables-in-node-js/).

Test Suite 1 (suite1.test.js):

```js
describe("Root of Suite 1", function () {

    describe("Function of Suite 1", function () {
        it("should do ..", async function () {
            ...
        });
    });
});
```

Test suite 2 (suite2.test.js):

```js
describe("Root of Suite 2", function () {

    // This will inform root suite about the completion of tests
    after(function () {
        global.isTestsCompleted = true;
    });

    describe("Function of Suite 2", function () {
        it("should do ..", async function () {
            ...
        });
    });
});
```

Root suite (root.test.js):

```js
const { isReady } = require("../db");

describe("Root Suite", function () {
    this.timeout(60000);

    // Wait until the DB connection is ready
    before(function (done) {
        isReady().then(() => done());
        global.isTestsCompleted = false;
    });

    // Check the variable every 500ms to see if all test suites executed
    after(function () {
       setInterval(() => {
           if (global.isTestsCompleted) {
               process.exit(1);
           }
       }, 500); 
    });

    require("./suite1.test.js");
    require("./suite2.test.js");
});
```

At above, order of suite requires important. They will be executed in the order we import them. Thus, we placed our control mechanism to the last suite, the `suite2.test.js`.

**Update**
There is also an internal option to terminate the process of mocha after all the test runs: `mocha --exit`.
So, we don't need to use a global variable in that case and the root suite would look as below:

```js
const { isReady } = require("../db");

describe("Root Suite", function () {
    this.timeout(60000);

    // Wait until the DB connection is ready
    before(function (done) {
        isReady().then(() => done());
    });

    require("./suite1.test.js");
    require("./suite2.test.js");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran into similar problem. I have solved it by nesting the suites.

This is my root suite:

```js
import utils from './utils'

describe('ROOT SUITE', function () {

  before(async function(){    
    await utils.before()    
    console.log('ROOT BEFORE')
  })

  // Require specs to consume
  require('require-dir')('./specs')

  after(async function(){
    await utils.after()
    console.log('ROOT AFTER')
  })  
})
```

And this is one of my suites:

```js
import utils from '../utils'

describe('General tests', function() {
  
  let app = null
  
  before(function(){
    app = utils.app
    console.log('local before')
  })
  after(function(){
    console.log('local after')
  })

  beforeEach(function(){
    console.log('local beforeEach')
  })
  afterEach(function(){
    console.log('local afterEach')
  })

  it('shows the proper application title', function () {
    return app.client.getTitle()
      .then(title => {
        expect(title).to.equal('electron-vue-testing-project')
      })
  }),
  it('is true', function () {
    return expect(true).to.be.true
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the [`json`](http://mochajs.org/#json-reporter) or [`json-stream`](http://mochajs.org/#json-stream-reporter) reporter.

```
mocha -R json >> your-file.json
```

Comment: No the problem is that would not have the variable definition for log. That would produce everything I console.log