# Mocha - is there a hook that executes after all test files have been run?

Tags: typescript, mocha.js

I was looking at: [Mocha run after all tests in all classes run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26761422/mocha-run-after-all-tests-in-all-classes-run) and wondering if this was the only solution?  It would be great to not have to nest all my tests.

I found this: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/typescript-and-mocha-hooks-c5d9ccffd58f
and was able to get it working:

```
export const mochaHooks = (): Mocha.RootHookObject => {
    return {
        afterAll(this: Mocha.Context) {
            console.log('In afterAll');

            const suite = runnable.parent;
            if (suite?.suites) {
                for (const innerSuite of suite?.suites) {
                    console.log(innerSuite.title);
            
                    for (const test of innerSuite.tests) {
                        console.log(test.title);
                        console.log(test.isPassed());
                    }
                }
            }
        },

    };
};
```

but it's being triggered after every file instead of after all files.  Does anyone know if there is a trick to make this work?  Can I somehow aggregate the data in memory over many calls to this hook?

Comment: Could probably do something with Node's beforeExit event... feels hacky though.

Comment: Are you running your tests in parallel? `afterAll` will run after all tests end, for each file if you are running it in parallel mode. If you change it to run the tests in serial mode, `afterAll` will run after all tests end, once only. See https://mochajs.org/#available-root-hooks

Comment: Yeah, afterAll is what I decided to do for now.  I was hoping to get an "after all files" but I can live without it for now and later if I really need it I can read the test run XML output and just use that.